# Redux thunk: how to await completion of an async action

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

As redux thunk calls functions returned by action creators asynchronously, how I can ensure after calling the action creator that redux has actually dispatched the action before moving on?

I need to fetch CSRF token before each POST request to server, and for both procedure there's an corresponding action.

The problem is, if I call those action creators successively, POST action is for some reason getting dispatched before CSRF action is dispatched. I want to keep these concerns separated, so I don't want to combine the actions.

How I can synchronize the action creator calling code with redux thunk dispatching those actions?

Answer (score 6):

You can make thunk action creator as Promise, make easier to control async jobs.

```
export function createXHRAction(xhrType, dispatch, options) {
    // you can customize createXHRAction here with options parameter.

    dispatch({ type: xhrType, data: { fetching: true, data: [] });

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        fetch(options.url, { ... })
        .then( (response) => {
            // to getting server response, you must use .json() method and this is promise object
            let parseJSONPromise = response.json();

            if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                parseJSONPromise.then( (result) => {
                    dispatch({ type: xhrType, data: { fetching: false, data: result.data });
                    resolve(result.data);
                });
                return parseJSONPromise;    // make possible to use then where calling this
            }
            else {
                return parseJSONPromise.then( res => {
                    reject({ message: res.error.message });
                });
            }
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            // handles common XHR error here
        });
    });
}
```

now you can easily create new XHR actions like this:

```
import { createXHRAction } from './actions';

export function getUser(id) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return createXHRAction('user', dispatch, {
            method: 'get',
            url: `/user/${id}`
        });
    };
}
```

now you can use thunk action like synchronous:

```
import { dispatch } from './store';
import { getUser } from './action/user';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    loadData(id) {

        // from here, store's state should be { fetching: true, data: [] }
        dispatch(getUser(id))
        .then( (userData) => {
            // now from here, you can get the value from parameter or you can get it from store or component props if super component passing it by redux provider.
            // store state should be { fetching: false: data [..., ...] }
            // do something with received data
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
        }));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for CSRF-token request to finish before starting POST request.

I think it would be better to wrap all that code into action creator

```
function postAction(data) {
   fetchToken().then((token) => {
       //you have got token here and can use it for the POST-request.
       doPost(data, token).then(() => {
          //dispatch success action if you need so
       })
   })
}
```

Comment: While this is a constructive workaround, there are cases where it would be very helpful to dispatch actions in sequence as the poster asked. E.g. you are working with a complicated project with trusted legacy code in existing action creators that "just works" and it's preferable to call those without modifying or refactoring.